# How to remove icons from context menu in Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, context-menu

After I updated my Firefox to 52(ubuntu), icons started to be seen in context menu.

I cannot see it in the preferences so, is there a way to remove them?

Comment: In my case, context menu icons have disappeared after the update to Firefox 52 on Ubuntu and I'm trying to get them back.Please post your answer if you can identify the setting

Comment: [http://winaero.com/blog/disable-icons-in-the-mozilla-firefox-context-menu/](http://winaero.com/blog/disable-icons-in-the-mozilla-firefox-context-menu/) Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This got worse with some much later version (me currently on 106 – actually a derivative of), as now icons added not only to context menus, but menu bars and menus herein, too.

Fortunately they can be removed again via the advanced settings. To edit, type `about:config` into the address bar and load the settings page (a local one). After confirming the warning, search for `icon` to get the relevant settings. These are:

- userChrome.icon.context_menu
- userChrome.icon.global_menu
- userChrome.icon.global_menubar
- userChrome.icon.menu

Setting these settings to `false` (by double-clicking) removes the icons while they can be re-enabled, if desired, by reverting the settings to `true`.